# Leaflet- How to use time dimension plugin with image overlay

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I am very new at Javascript.

I am trying to create animation with my monthly soil moisture output (.png format) on OpenStreetMap using the Leaflet package. I could use the time slider plugin to move images but I also want a play button that is available in the '[TimeDimension](https://github.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension)' plugin.

I have 150 images to display. I looked [into the demo](http://apps.socib.es/Leaflet.TimeDimension/examples/) but I could not understand where to start as a beginner.

Is there any simplified example or instruction of using the plugin?

[image: This is how it looks like]

Comment: If you use PNG overlays then the best exemple would be this one : http://apps.socib.es/Leaflet.TimeDimension/examples/example10.html . Are the PNG locally on your computer or online ? If they are online and open, can you share a fiddle of your code ?

Comment: @ Léo M Thanks for your quick reply! I looked into this example but could not really understand how to adapt it to my work. The PNGs are not available online. I have uploaded 5 files along with the code in this link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Wq1K6aNStyDtCVuFSpJMr-hpoWoAFz3o?usp=sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution without using the **TimeDimension** plugin (because this plugin is meant to be used primarily with WMS and GeoJSON, they have an example with ImageOverlay but say that it is just a "proof-of-concept" and I find it overly complicated for the result).

I coded with the following assumptions based on what you sent:

- All the PNG files are named in the following syntax: **month_year.png** with only the first 3 letters of the month and a uppercase at the first letter of the month.
- Your PNG files are stored at the same place as the script. If not, modify the variable **urlPrefix**

[image]

HTML

```
<div id="map"></div>
<div class="slidecontainer">
      <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" class="slider" id="slider"><label id="sliderLabel"></label>
</div>
<button id="play">Play</button><button id="stop">Stop</button>
```

JS

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([22, 78.5], 5, {
    crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326
});

var basemaps = {
    'Topo Map': L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326
    }),

    'Geo World Map': L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/NatGeo_World_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
        crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326
    }),

};

L.control.layers(basemaps).addTo(map);

basemaps["Topo Map"].addTo(map);

var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(
    new L.LatLng(40, 59),
    new L.LatLng(4, 98));
map.fitBounds(bounds);



var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']

// add all your years here (e.g. [1982,1983,1984,1985])
var years = [1982]

//storing all possible times
var timeValues = []
for(var i in years){
    for(var y in months){
        timeValues.push(months[y]+"_"+years[i])
    }
}

//setting max value of the slider
document.getElementById("slider").max = ""+timeValues.length+"";

//setting default label of the slider
document.getElementById("sliderLabel").innerHTML = timeValues[0]

//change the prefix of the url if your images are not in the same folder as your script
var urlPrefix = ""

var url = urlPrefix+timeValues[0]+".png"

var imageOverlay = new L.ImageOverlay(url, bounds, {
    opacity: 0.7,
    interactive: false,

}).addTo(map);


//function when sliding
slider.oninput = function() {
  //changing the label
  document.getElementById("sliderLabel").innerHTML = timeValues[this.value-1]
  //setting the url of the overlay
  imageOverlay.setUrl(urlPrefix+timeValues[this.value-1]+".png")
}

var playTimeOut;

function play() {
    playTimeOut = setTimeout(function () {
        //increasing the slider by 1 (if not already at the end)
        var val = document.getElementById("slider").value
        console.log(val)
        //if end of slider, stopping
        if(val == document.getElementById("slider").max){
            clearTimeout(playTimeOut);
              //hidding the stop button
              document.getElementById('stop').style.display = "none";
              //showing the play button
              document.getElementById('play').style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
        document.getElementById("slider").value = Number(val)+1
        play()
        }
        //changing the label
        document.getElementById("sliderLabel").innerHTML = timeValues[Number(val)-1]
        //setting the url of the overlay
        imageOverlay.setUrl(urlPrefix+timeValues[Number(val)-1]+".png")

    }, 1000);
}

document.getElementById('play').onclick = function(e){
  play()
  //showing the stop button
  document.getElementById('stop').style.display = "block";
  //hidding the play button
  document.getElementById('play').style.display = "none";
}

document.getElementById('stop').onclick = function(e){
  clearTimeout(playTimeOut);
  //hidding the stop button
  document.getElementById('stop').style.display = "none";
  //showing the play button
  document.getElementById('play').style.display = "block";
}

//hidding the stop button by default
document.getElementById('stop').style.display = "none";
```

Comment: It looks like the statement `var slider = document.getElementById('slider');` is missing before `slider.oninput` call.

Comment: Looks like it is not needed, the code works without, as well as this example: https://jsfiddle.net/k39ne8r4/  (but I'm a bit surprised it does actually ...)

Comment: Each day one can learn something new :-)

Comment: Indeed :) That's strange, even a **slider.max = 10** works to set the maximum ... I always used Jquery or getElementById() for those, never realized it could work without (not in all cases though I suppose).

Comment: Thank you so much @LéoM!! It works. I really appreciate your time and effort.