# How can I access a Folium map from within JavaScript/Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, mapping, folium

I am working on a Folium map and am trying to inject parts of the leaflet/js solution suggested [in this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/337975/leaflet-how-to-use-time-dimension-plugin-with-image-overlay/438278#438278) in my code.

My map has already been initialized in Folium, so I don't want to initialize it again with Leaflet and create another map on top of the Folium map, but instead access the Folium map from the JavaScript code. How can I do this? I tried

```js
var map=window.maps.leafletList[0].map.getCenter()
```

but this didn't work.

Another way I tried to solve it was to initialize a completely blank map in folium

```js
m = folium.Map(crs='Simple', zoom_start=2, tiles=None)
```

and then initialize the map in Leaflet, but it seems that when I add markers in Folium later on, these are still placed on the 'blank' folium map underneath and not the Leaflet map that I added on top?

I am totally new to this.

Comment: Can I ask why you don’t just use leaflet? Instead of trying to mix the two? Folium is a “light-weight” Leaflet for Python /R. It generates all the calls and scripts for you. There are “plug-in” for Folium that add some of the Leaflet tools / features for you. Open your leaflet map in a text editor and look for yourself. Chances are you will be able to replicate it in Leaflet, with the full Leaflet capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - my python/folium code is pretty much completed and this is an additional feature in my code I wanted to integrate, so instead of rewriting my whole code using leaflet/js I would prefer if there was a way to integrate it in my already existing python/folium code.

Comment: You can access the leaflet in folium but its very hackish I would not advise this. You are better off just bulding it from pure leaflet or look into ipyleaflet which has greater interactivity with user

Comment: I'll give it a try with ipyleaflet, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate javascript with:

```
from folium.elements import *

my_js = '''
console.log('here add your code javascript')
'''

m.get_root().script.add_child(Element(my_js))
```

where m is the variable of map folium. Too you can invoke a file .js or .css:

```
m.get_root().html.add_child(JavascriptLink('./static/js/script.js'))
m.get_root().header.add_child(CssLink('./static/css/style.css'))
```